# Uxie, Azelf not appearing

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I am playing through Omega Ruby and have recently found Nameless Cavern. I went in and encountered Mesprit. A few hours later I encountered Uxie. I captured both and encountered Azelf. I then dropped my 3ds and the game came out. Me, being forgetful, had not saved since halfway through the Delta Episode, which I had recently completed. I went back through and recovered most of my progress. However, upon entering Nameless Cavern, I discovered no response at the times Uxie and Azelf should appear. I reencountered and recaptured Mesprit, but I can't reencounter Uxie or Azelf for some reason. I have met all the friendship requirements, so why can't I fight them? Please respond as soon as you find this.

Comment: A guy here had a similar problem with Kyurem recently. Have you tried beating the Elite Four? It should trigger the respawn of the Legendaries.

Comment: I haven't re encountered then since I lost my progress, so they shouldn't need to respawn. I will try this, however I dont see how it will change things. And this case is different than that one as I had encountered them and lost my progress.